# how to access input variables in redshift SQL function by name

Tags: sql, plsql, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a Redshift SQL function and trying to access input variables by its names.

```
create or replace 
function sql_udf_test (inp1 int, inp2 int)
 returns int
stable
as $$
select inp1+inp2
$$ language sql;
```

**Error**

> SQL Error [500310] [42703]: Amazon Invalid operation: column
> "inp1" does not exist;

However when I trying to access input variable by its index its working fine.

```
create or replace 
function sql_udf_test (inp1 int, inp2 int)
 returns int
stable
as $$
select $1+$2
$$ language sql;

select sql_udf_test(1, 2);
```

**Output:**

> 3

Any suggestions, may be I am doing some beginner mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in the [amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) that in SQL UDF, You have to use the $1, $2, so on to refer to the function input parameters and Names of the parameters can be used in the Python UDF.

> In a Python UDF, refer to arguments using the argument names. In a
> SQL UDF, refer to arguments using $1, $2, and so on, based on the
> order of the arguments in the argument list.

Comment: Also it states, that there should not be any argument names: *For a Python UDF, a list of input argument names and data types. For a SQL UDF, a list of data types, **without argument names**.*

Comment: Yeap @astentx. Perfect!!

Comment: @astentx  Thanks I got that, actually functions is compiling with input var names in sql, that's why I was confused that may be there is way to access.

Comment: @Popeye Surely, I missed the point mentioned by you in the documentation. Thanks